# how to display a real 0 as 0 and not as empty in grid's templatefield?

Tags: sql, asp.net, gridview

One thing I always stumble over and end up resigning with a dirty workaround:

In order to display a percentage in a Gridview's TemplateField's Label I usually want to do this: (with the datasource providing a real number)

```
<asp:Label ID="LabelPercentage" runat="server" Text = '<%# Bind("Percentage","{0:#}&nbsp;%") %>'>
```

This returns nice percentages, but has 2 ugly side effects:

- the persentage symbol is always displayed even though the percentage
  is NULL
- 0 is not displayed at all. It becomes an empty spot with a    leading
  %

So my ugly and complicated workaround -especially if I want the column to allow sorting by percentage- is done on the datasource side: in sql I do:

```
CAST(CAST(ROUND(100.0*score/cases,0) as int) as nvarchar) + ' %'
```

there must be an easier way!!!?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something like **COALESCE** to avoid `null`.
For example.

```
SELECT COALESCE(null, 0)
```

This would return 0.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't to precise in explaining. It's not about the NULL that I want to display as 0. It's about the 0 that I want to be displayed a 0. With the formatting {0:#} I surpress all the decimals. But as the label would display a 0.6789 as .6789 leaving the zero away, in the end I don't get anything for any value between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for NULL inline with a ternary operator.

```
<%# Eval("Percentage") == null ? "yourValue" : Eval("Percentage","{0:#}&nbsp;%") %>
```